# Creating foreach loop through JSON numerically indexed stdclass objects

Tags: php, json, loops, foreach

I am trying to get data from the musixmatch api,  have managed to connect with success but am struggling to print a value from a numerically indexed stdclass object

here is one result from my json:

```html
{
  "message": {
    "header": {
      "status_code": 200,
      "execute_time": 0.016516923904419,
      "available": 685
    },
    "body": {
      "track_list": [
        {
          "track": {
            "track_id": 13799336,
            "track_mbid": "cc72094f-baa3-4017-b628-d95bf1087144",
            "track_isrc": "",
            "track_spotify_id": "",
            "track_soundcloud_id": "",
            "track_xboxmusic_id": "",
            "track_name": "Accents",
            "track_name_translation_list": [
              
            ],
            "track_rating": 1,
            "track_length": 238,
            "commontrack_id": 9433434,
            "instrumental": 0,
            "explicit": 0,
            "has_lyrics": 0,
            "has_lyrics_crowd": 0,
            "has_subtitles": 0,
            "has_richsync": 0,
            "num_favourite": 0,
            "lyrics_id": 0,
            "subtitle_id": 0,
            "album_id": 13799348,
            "album_name": "X-Posed: The Interview",
            "artist_id": 33491916,
            "artist_mbid": "e0140a67-e4d1-4f13-8a01-364355bee46e",
            "artist_name": "Justin Bieber",
            "album_coverart_100x100": "http:\/\/s.mxmcdn.net\/images-storage\/albums\/nocover.png",
            "album_coverart_350x350": "",
            "album_coverart_500x500": "",
            "album_coverart_800x800": "",
            "track_share_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Justin-Bieber\/Accents?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=Song+Find%3A1409613795717",
            "track_edit_url": "https:\/\/www.musixmatch.com\/lyrics\/Justin-Bieber\/Accents\/edit?utm_source=application&utm_campaign=api&utm_medium=Song+Find%3A1409613795717",
            "commontrack_vanity_id": "Justin-Bieber\/Accents",
            "restricted": 0,
            "first_release_date": "2011-04-05T00:00:00Z",
            "updated_time": "2017-04-28T14:06:57Z",
            "primary_genres": {
              "music_genre_list": [
                
              ]
            },
            "secondary_genres": {
              "music_genre_list": [
                
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my attempt at getting the track_name

```html
$url = file_get_contents("http://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/track.search?q_artist=justin%20bieber&apikey=MYAPIKEY");
$json = json_decode($url);

foreach($json->message->body->track_list->track as $track) {
echo $track->track_name;
}
```

The code above doesnt print anything but if I do

```html
$tracks = $json->message->body->track_list['0']->track->track_name;
```

It will print the track name, but of course I would like to print all the track_name values from each track in the list

Any help appreciated

Comment: Please review your error reporting settings. The code you say that doesn't print anything should be printing `Notice: Trying to get property 'track' of non-object`.

Comment: You are having single track in your data. If their are more tracks you can iterate the loop as described by @WebCode.ie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over the track_list array as follows:

```
$url = file_get_contents("http://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/track.search?q_artist=justin%20bieber&apikey=MYAPIKEY");
$json = json_decode($url);

foreach($json->message->body->track_list as $track_list) {
    echo $track_list->track->track_name;
}
```